# Recommended backup strategy for Firebase

Tags: python, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am setting up a Firebase backend for a mobile app and wanted to ask what is the recommended way to backup our data.

Here what I got so far.
In your backend we use the services:

- Authentication for the user credentials
- Firestore for the user data
- Storage for pictures which are referenced by the user data

Regarding the backup I have found some strategies already:

*For the backup of Firestore:* I did follow this advice ([link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export)) and use a scheduled nodejs function to export the data into an own storage. And later for the import I can do this with the Firestore Ui of google computing platform. – I have tested this and it is working for me.

*For the Storage:*
I have found a solution using rsync and a scheduled job. However I also found the google cloud platform "Data Transfer Service", which does copy the data into another bucket – without any code from me… - So this covers the Storage for me

*For backing up the Authentication data:* I have not found anything which really helped….

So I got three questions:

1. How should I backup my data from the Authentication service?
2. Now including the solution from my previous question I will probably end up with a 3rd way of interaction with Firebase/google cloud platform:

- A NodeJS script for Firebase
- The Transfer Service for the Storage
- And the Authentication solution

So I am really interested if this is the recommended way of doing backups of a Firebase backend for a mobile platform, or is there some kind of "best practices" for this? I also thought to put everything into a big python script to have at least everything in one script and let this do the exports and transfers... My Idea is to do a backup ~ once per day.

3. But nevertheless if I keep everything seperated or I put everything into a big python script what worries me in either case is the point of what might happen in case someone writes something during this backup? Maybe a user uploads a new image which would change the Firestore and the Storage during the backup process. How can I make sure to keep me data consistent?

Comment: One option is to use built in tools that Firebase provides - see [Automated Backups](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/backups).

Comment: Hi Jay, this is correct, but the link you have posted it for the Realtime database only. But I am using Firestore as a database. There, as far is I know, the only way to do scheduled backups is this nodejs script which I linked in my question above.

Comment: oops! My apologies. I missed the Firestore reference. I go back and forth so much I overlook it from time to time. Obviously google import/export is way to dump your data to a local device (if that's an option) but it doesn't do Auth. I have not used it but the Admin SDK offers auth import and export functions. I think you pretty well have it covered as far as getting the data. If the data changes while backing up? That's a challenge - is your app something that could notify the users and stop write access while the backup is occurring? I can't imagine it would take more than a few minutes.

Comment: Hi Jay, all good :-) I will then try to export the auth data as you mentioned using the Admin SDK. Regarding the consistency I got an idea: Since on our project we cannot lock the database, a way might be to let the users always write "short term database". Then a cloud function would then copy the data from there into the correct database in case the data is "valid"... This could be stopped during the export and then enable it later. I will think about this, but in any case thank you for your help :-)